# Count overall time between two timestamps per user

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I'm stuck with some MySQL queries.
I have a table like this:

```
ID|USERID|USERNAME|STARTTIME|ENDTIME|COMMITTYPE
```

The users click buttons in a frontend -> Start <- and -> Stop <-.
This creates a db entry with their respective duties, starttime and endtime. So, each click on start creates a new row/entry in the db and will get finished by the click on the stop button.

My problem, is there a chance to count the overall time between the start time and the end time per user and commit type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably work

```
SELECT USERID, COMMITTYPE, MIN(STARTTIME), MAX(ENDTIME), 
SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIME_DIFF(ENDTIME - STARTTIME))/3600) hours FROM tablename
GROUP BY USERID, COMMITTYPE
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you refer to something like this?

```
SELECT COMMITTYPE, USER, (ENDTIME - STARTTIME) AS ELLAPSED_TIME
FROM YOUR_TABLE GROUP BY COMMITTYPE, USERID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('new_date', 'old_date');

// eg

SELECT DATEDIFF('2006-04-01','2006-04-01');
```

IG GETTING USE LINUX

```
<?php

  // Set timezone
  date_default_timezone_set("UTC");

  // Time format is UNIX timestamp or
  // PHP strtotime compatible strings
  function dateDiff($time1, $time2, $precision = 6) {
    // If not numeric then convert texts to unix timestamps
    if (!is_int($time1)) {
      $time1 = strtotime($time1);
    }
    if (!is_int($time2)) {
      $time2 = strtotime($time2);
    }

    // If time1 is bigger than time2
    // Then swap time1 and time2
    if ($time1 > $time2) {
      $ttime = $time1;
      $time1 = $time2;
      $time2 = $ttime;
    }

    // Set up intervals and diffs arrays
    $intervals = array('year','month','day','hour','minute','second');
    $diffs = array();

    // Loop thru all intervals
    foreach ($intervals as $interval) {
      // Create temp time from time1 and interval
      $ttime = strtotime('+1 ' . $interval, $time1);
      // Set initial values
      $add = 1;
      $looped = 0;
      // Loop until temp time is smaller than time2
      while ($time2 >= $ttime) {
        // Create new temp time from time1 and interval
        $add++;
        $ttime = strtotime("+" . $add . " " . $interval, $time1);
        $looped++;
      }

      $time1 = strtotime("+" . $looped . " " . $interval, $time1);
      $diffs[$interval] = $looped;
    }

    $count = 0;
    $times = array();
    // Loop thru all diffs
    foreach ($diffs as $interval => $value) {
      // Break if we have needed precission
      if ($count >= $precision) {
 break;
      }
      // Add value and interval 
      // if value is bigger than 0
      if ($value > 0) {
 // Add s if value is not 1
 if ($value != 1) {
   $interval .= "s";
 }
 // Add value and interval to times array
 $times[] = $value . " " . $interval;
 $count++;
      }
    }

    // Return string with times
    return implode(", ", $times);
  }

?>
```

///

```
echo dateDiff("2010-01-26", "2004-01-26") . "\n";
echo dateDiff("2006-04-12 12:30:00", "1987-04-12 12:30:01") . "\n";
echo dateDiff("now", "now +2 months") . "\n";
echo dateDiff("now", "now -6 year -2 months -10 days") . "\n";
echo dateDiff("2009-01-26", "2004-01-26 15:38:11") . "\n";
```

**OUTPUT**

> 6 years
>   18 years, 11 months, 30 days, 23 hours, 59 minutes, 59 seconds 2
>   months 6 years, 2 months, 10 days 4 years, 11 months, 30 days, 8
>   hours, 21 minutes, 49 seconds